# Tab completion for aliased sub commands in zsh: alias gco='git checkout'

Tags: git, zsh, tab-completion

I have an alias: `alias gco='git checkout'`

How can I add tab completion as if I had typed `git checkout`?

For my `alias g='git'` I use `compdef g='git'`.

I've been trying to use `compdef` but I've not had any success.

Comment: In zsh, it just works for me as soon as I define an alias (without `compdef` or anything). Did you try it?

Comment: Yes I have tried that., I just get file completion.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You don’t need to do anything, especially `compdef g='git'`, it should work without any configuration. You would need something only if you used function in place of an alias.

Comment: I just get file completion. I've notices oh-my-zsh uses compdef; https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh

Comment: @WilliamBettridge-Radford These people must have done something to disable default behavior or just doing unecessary job. Just do `zsh -f<CR>autoload -Uz compinit<CR>compinit<CR>alias gco='git checkout'<CR>gco <Tab>`. I see a list of refs in this case. Another test: `alias g='git'<CR>compdef g='hg'<CR>g <Tab>`: `compdef` is simply ignored, I get completion for git and not mercurial and am needing `compdef git='hg'` to override the behavior (obviously for both alias and `git`).

Comment: That worked, thank you kindly. I'm using a fork of dotfiles from github. I think I'll turn them all off then add them back in slowly.

https://github.com/holman/dotfiles

Comment: My problem was that I was in fact using functions. Thanks!

Comment: My problem was that aliases were set up before the completions. Moving those aliases to be AFTER completion setup made them work.

Answer (score 27):

Disable this option and you're also good...

```
# don't expand aliases _before_ completion has finished
#   like: git comm-[tab]
# setopt complete_aliases
```

Comment: This did it for me. Just to make it clear, you want to comment out that line in this response, not make your `config.zsh` look like it. You should **not** be setting the complete_aliases option if you want to have completion for aliases.

Answer (score 7):

For me adding both of `complete_aliases` and `compdef` is necessary to get below snippet work:

```
alias docker-compose-dev='docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-dev.yml'

compdef docker-compose-dev='docker-compose'
setopt complete_aliases
```